# bigquery get highest possible steps group by col

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i have question about counting row number based on a column iteration

my table looks like this

```
time  | steps  | name
13:02 | 0      | a
13:03 | 0      | a
13:04 | 1      | a
13:05 | 0      | a
13:07 | 1      | a
13:10 | 1      | a
13:12 | 2      | a
13:04 | 0      | b
13:06 | 0      | b
13:12 | 1      | b
13:14 | 2      | b
13:19 | 3      | b
13:14 | 0      | b
13:19 | 3      | b
```

from table above i want to get the highest possible steps made by name. but must meet these condition:

1. steps made by name must be sequential(ex: 0,1,2,3 return 0,1,2,3; 0,1,2,4 return 0,1,2)
2. each step must be sequential according to time
3. Select any value if there are more than 1 record is possible(ex: 0,1,1,2 return 0,ANY(1,1),2)

table i looking for is

```
time  | steps  | name
13:05 | 0      | a
13:07 | 1      | a
13:12 | 2      | a
13:06 | 0      | b
13:12 | 1      | b
13:14 | 2      | b
13:19 | 3      | b
```

Is there any way i can do this in bigquery?

Answer (score 0):

First remove duplicates.  Then identify the rows where the "next" step (by time) is what you expect.

The following *almost* works:

```
select t.*
from (select min(time) as time, steps, name,
             lead(steps) over (partition by name order by min(time)) as next_step
      from yourtable t
      group by steps, name
     ) t
where next_step = step + 1;
```

However, you want the minimum set.  For that, you also need for the row number to match. It turns out that that condition is sufficient:

```
select t.*
from (select min(time) as time, steps, name,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by min(time)) as seqnum
      from yourtable t
      group by steps, name
     ) t
where step = seqnum - 1;
```

Comment: I don't think this preserves the sequence.  For example, if you insert a 0 before the 2 value for 'a' you still get 0, 1, 2.  @R Herpradipto Adiansyah, can there be a break in the sequence?